# Keep all previous data according to condition

Tags: php

I am trying to display two product names depending on a counter. I've declared a session variable 'counter'. I want to show the first product name if the button is clicked, and I want to show two product names if the button is clicked again.

> Dell
>
> Mac

However, if I click the button the second time, the second product name replaces the first product name; I want both products to display.

How would I fix this?

My code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connect.php');

// if counter is not set, set to zero
if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}

// if button is pressed, increment counter
if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
    ++$_SESSION['counter'];
    // Get data according to id 

    $userid2 = $_POST['id2'];
    $query3 = "select * from product where  id='" . $userid2 . "'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
    $data3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);

    if ($_SESSION['counter'] == 1) {
        echo $data3['name'] . "<br>";
    }

    if ($_SESSION['counter'] == 2) {
        echo $data3['name'];
    }
}

// reset counter
if (isset($_POST['reset'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}

$query2 = "select * from product ";
$result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$sr = $data['sr'];
$name = $data['name'];
$price = $data['price'];
$qunt = $data['quantity'];

$total += $data['price'];

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <?PHP
                echo "<tr><td>" . $data['id'] . "</td><td>" . $sr . "</td><td >" . $name . "</a></td><td>" . $price . "</td><td>" . $qunt . "</td> ";
                ?>
            <tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="id2" value="<?php echo $data['id'] ?>"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['counter']; ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Counter"/>
        <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset"/>

        <br/><?php echo $_SESSION['counter']; ?>
    </form>
<?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make your second request, you're losing your current state; you no longer have access to the first product name. One way to fix this is to add a second session variable to keep track of products, as such:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connect.php');

// if counter is not set, set to zero
if (!isset($_SESSION['counter']) || !isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
    // Create a new array in your session
    $_SESSION['products'] = array();
}

// if button is pressed, increment counter
if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
    ++$_SESSION['counter'];
    // Get data according to id

    $userid2 = $_POST['id2'];
    $query3 = "select * from product where  id='" . $userid2 . "'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
    $data3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);

    // Add to your products session array
    $_SESSION['products'][] = $data3['name'];

    // Reduce to two products
    $_SESSION['products'] = array_slice($_SESSION['products'], -2, 2);

    // Print each product in your products array, max of two
    foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $name) {
        echo $name . "<br />";
    }
}

// reset counter
else if (isset($_POST['reset'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['products'] = array();
}

$query2 = "select * from product ";
$result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$sr = $data['sr'];
$name = $data['name'];
$price = $data['price'];
$qunt = $data['quantity'];

$total += $data['price'];

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <?= "<tr><td>" . $data['id'] . "</td><td>" . $sr . "</td><td >" . $name . "</a></td><td>" . $price . "</td><td>" . $qunt . "</td> " ?>
            <tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="id2" value="<?= $data['id'] ?>"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?= $_SESSION['counter'] ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Counter"/>
        <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset"/>

        <br/><?= $_SESSION['counter']; ?>
    </form>
<?php }
?>
```

---

Something to keep in mind: the use of mysql_* functions is [deprecated](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing), and frankly, dangerous to use in new development. You can't use prepared statements with those functions, which means that anyone can seriously mess with your database. Read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but problem is it shows product name more than two times. I need only two product name will show.

Comment: That's fine; I just added an array_slice. That will keep the most recent two products in the products list. If you want the first two products clicked on, then you'd replace -2 with 0

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `if` block something like this

```
if($_SESSION['counter']==1 || $_SESSION['counter']==2) {
  echo $data3['name']."<br>";
}
```

that way first product will display in both condition

**Update**

I would do it like this, don't store a counter value in session, store the product ids as `array`, then you can just use `count()` to get the number of products in session

that way you can query the db for stored ids like this

```
$query3 = "select * from product where id IN (1,2);
```

and just list it on page

note: dont use `mysql_*` api, its deprecated use PDO its secure and supports many databases;